# What indexes are needed for the following scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a single table holding stock of single-use voucher codes. Each row is a separate code. For simplicity the table looks like this:

```
| id (AUTO_INCREMENTING) | owner (VARCHAR) | brand (VARCHAR) | currency (CHAR) | value (INTEGER) | activated_at (TIMESTAMP) | expires_at (DATE) |
|------------------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|--------------------------|-------------------|
| 1                      | first-owner     | brand-one       | gbp             | 10              | NULL                     | 2018-06-06        |
| 2                      | second-owner    | brand-one       | gbp             | 15              | NULL                     | 2018-06-06        |
| 3                      | second-owner    | brand-one       | gbp             | 15              | NULL                     | 2018-06-06        |
```

*I know I can normalise the table and extract all the fields into their own tables and have the `stock` table just contain the `ids`, however so far that hasn't proven to give a performance gain, and, for the sake of simplicity and user readability I am inclined to leave it as is.*

**When querying this table, I want to be able to optionally pass the *owner*, the *brand*, or both.**

What indexes do I need on this table for the following queries and *why*?

Querying the table without supplying an *owner* or *brand*:

```
SELECT
    `owner`,
    `brand`,
    `currency`,
    `value`,
    count(*) AS 'quantity_of_codes',
    (count(*) * `value`) AS 'total_face_value'
FROM `inventory`
WHERE `activated_at` IS NULL
AND `expires_at` >= '2018-06-05'
GROUP BY `owner`, `brand`, `currency`, `value`
```

If I run `explain` I can see that the index is used:

```
| select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                                     |
|-------------|-----------|------|---------------|-----|---------|-------|--------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| SIMPLE      | inventory | ref  |               |     | 766     | const | 416144 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

When I supply an *owner* the index is used but it creates a temporary table and uses *filesort* which I believe isn't good.

```
SELECT
    `brand`,
    `owner`,
    `currency`,
    `value`,
    count(*) AS 'quantity_of_codes',
    (count(*) * `value`) AS 'total_face_value'
FROM `inventory`
WHERE `owner` = 'first-owner'
AND `activated_at` IS NULL
AND `expires_at` >= '2017-06-06'
GROUP BY `brand`, `owner`, `currency`, `value`
```

Running `explain` shows:

```
| select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                                            | key                                                      | key_len | ref | rows | Extra                                                     |
|-------------|-----------|-------|----------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|---------|-----|------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| SIMPLE      | inventory | index | brand_owner_currency_value_activated_at_expires_at_index | brand_owner_currency_value_activated_at_expires_at_index | 2310    |     | 87   | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

When I also provide a *brand* I get:

```
SELECT
    `brand`,
    `owner`,
    `currency`,
    `value`,
    count(*) AS 'quantity_of_codes',
    (count(*) * `value`) AS 'total_face_value'
FROM `inventory`
WHERE `owner` = 'first-owner'
AND `brand` = 'brand-one'
AND `activated_at` IS NULL
AND `expires_at` >= '2018-06-05'
GROUP BY `brand`, `owner`, `currency`, `value`
```

Lastly, when I run `explain` I get:

```
| select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                                            | key                                                      | key_len | ref | rows | Extra                                                     |
|-------------|-----------|------|----------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|---------|-----|------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| SIMPLE      | inventory | ref  | brand_owner_currency_value_activated_at_expires_at_index | brand_owner_currency_value_activated_at_expires_at_index | 1532    |     | 1    | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

As mentioned, I have an index across the *brand*, *owner*, *currency*, *value*, *activated_at*, and *expires_at* fields although this isn't used when I don't include *brand* in the where part of the query.

Comment: By *supply an owner, or a brand, or both* I assume you mean *add to my query `WHERE` terms filtering on equality on the `owner` or `brand` columns, or both.* When you add equality filters you fundamentally change the way the query planner chooses an index to use. The fallback is always a full table scan. It's rare that the query planner chooses an index because it's somehow close to the right one.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a fine reference for getting the chops to design your indexes skilfully.

You're on the right track by choosing a compound index for this kind of query. Your query has these `WHERE`-clause items.

```
 WHERE `owner` = 'an-owner'
   AND `activated_at` IS NULL
   AND `expires_at` >= '2017-06-06'
```

You're looking for equality on the first item, `IS NULL` on the second one, and a range scan on the third.  So, an index on `(owner, activated_at, expires_at)` can allow the query planner to jump to the correct row and then scan the index for consecutive rows. An index on `(activated_at, owner, expires_at)` will also work.

Your index, on `( brand, owner, currency, value, _activated_at, _expires_at)` can't be range scanned for the query you showed. So the query planner ignores it.

Pro tip: Don't create indexes for tables just because they seem like they might be useful. Design them to speed up the queries you need sped up.

Pro tip #2: **Using temporary; Using filesort** is not a sure sign of poor performance. *temporary* means that some result set needs to be put into an ephemeral table-like data structure in the server. *filesort* means that result set needs sorting before delivery. When you use `GROUP BY` the query planner often needs a *temporary* structure to fulfill your query. Read this.  https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Your `EXPLAIN` output looks pretty darn good to me. One row? Great,

Comment: I did have an index across the _owner_, _activated_at_, and _expires_at_ fields but it wasn't used when I use the `GROUP BY`. I have also updated my question.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I were to split out the four fields into separate tables and use foreign keys? What indexes would I need for the three variations - owner and brand, only owner, and neither?

Comment: I added to my answer.  With respect, you are on the verge of overthinking this problem. You're very close to being done.

Comment: Thank you, the query still runs rather slowly with a larger data set, even though the variations in owner, brand, currency, and value haven't increased. There will always be a constraint on the activated_at and expires_at dates so should they go first in the WHERE clause, or should I put the owner and brand first (when they are supplied)?

Comment: Order of clauses makes no difference in `WHERE`.  You may want to work on optimizing one query at a time. You may want to read up on covering indexes.

Comment: Would you suggest having (up to) three separate indexes based on whether I am supplying an owner and a brand, jus an owner, or neither? I have gone through the slides here https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really and I think I understand

Comment: Yes. You are trying to handle multiple queries of the form `a=x AND b=y AND c=z AND d=q AND datestamp >= constant`  You have varying combinations of the `a,b,c,d` criteria. To achieve an index scan on the `datestamp` criterion you need *precisely* the equality criteria columns, then the `datestamp` column, in the index. An extra equality criterion column in the index will render it useless for the query. Do go read the reference on indexing.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what index I should use on the first query shown above when I don't include an owner or brand in the where clause. I have updated the explain.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT brand, owner, currency, value,
       count(*) AS quantity_of_codes, sum(value) AS total_face_value
FROM inventory i
WHERE owner = 'an-owner' AND
      activated_at IS NULL AND 
      expires_at >= '2017-06-06'
GROUP BY brand, owner, currency, value;
```

For this query, the best index would be `inventory(owner, activated_at, expires_at)`.  These columns in this order can be used for the `WHERE` clause.  In MySQL there is not much that you can do about the `GROUP BY`.